# How to COUNT a value in a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have a column where I flag two values (0 and 1). How can I select all from the table but only counting the value 1 from the flag column?

SQL Server

Comment: `COUNT(CASE WHEN flag = 1 then 1 END)` this should work

Comment: What do you want returned?  Only the count of 1s?

Comment: Would really help to see sample data and expected results to clairify your question.... Maybe you want the total count of all 1 flags from all records in the table, but display that total on each record?
 `SELECT A.*, sum(flag) over (partition by null) as SumTotalOfFlag FROM Table A`

Answer (score 1):

You need a `COUNT` with `CASE` expression, like this:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN flag = 1 then 1 END)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return all of your values and also have a total count (using sort of logic) you could use a window function aggregation using [**`over`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) like so:

```
select 
    t.*
  , count(case when flag = 1 then 1 end) over(partition by 1) as flag_1_count
from t
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure I understand the question, but wouldn't it be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE flag = 1
```

Comment: Or if you actually want the count, SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table WHERE flag = 1

Answer (score 0):

Err, are you asking how to perform a simple select statement or am I missing something...
Like this?

```
SELECT *
FROM [YourTableName]
WHERE FlagColumnName = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
Select count(0) 
from YourTableName
where ValueField = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you mean something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [YOUR_TABLE] WHERE [FLAGCOLUMN] = 1;
```